# RFC PS Rasterizer Library API

Tags: c, image, library, postscript

We've got the basic functionality of using my postscript interpreter, `xpost`, as a library. I'd like to solicit some feedback from the community on the API setup. This example program, called `xpost_client.c` illustrates the API to rasterize a small EPS into a 792x612 BGR buffer, which it then dumps to a file as an ASCII PPM file (so you can check it with a text editor).

```
/* 
   This is a simple example of a client calling xpost as a library 
   with a postscript program, desiring the raster data of the 
   generated image. 

TODO: 
    define buffer interchange type 
 */ 

#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <stdio.h> 

#include "xpost.h" 
#include "xpost_memory.h" 
#include "xpost_object.h" 
#include "xpost_context.h" 
#include "xpost_interpreter.h" 

char *prog = 
    "%%BoundingBox: 200 300 400 500\n" 
    "300 400 100 0 360 arc\n" 
    "fill\n" 
    "showpage\n"; 

int main() { 
    void *buffer_type_object; 
    xpost_init(); 
    xpost_create("bgr", 
            XPOST_OUTPUT_BUFFEROUT, 
            &buffer_type_object, 
            XPOST_SHOWPAGE_RETURN, 
            1); 
    xpost_run(XPOST_INPUT_STRING, prog); 
    { 
        unsigned char *buffer = buffer_type_object; 
        int i,j; 
        FILE *fp = fopen("xpost_client_out.ppm", "w"); 
        fprintf(fp, "P3\n612 792\n255\n"); 
        for (i=0; i<792; i++) { 
            for (j=0; j<612; j++) { 
                unsigned int red, green, blue; 
                red = *buffer++; 
                green = *buffer++; 
                blue = *buffer++; 
                ++buffer; 
                fprintf(fp, "%d ", red); 
                fprintf(fp, "%d ", green); 
                fprintf(fp, "%d ", blue); 
                if ((j%20)==0) 
                    fprintf(fp, "\n"); 
            } 
            fprintf(fp, "\n"); 
        } 
        fclose(fp); 
    } 
    xpost_destroy(); 
    free(buffer_type_object); 
    xpost_quit(); 
    return 0;
}
```

Currently only the bgr device offers the `OUTPUT_BUFFEROUT` option. The C code assumes that the PS program contains a `showpage` to trigger the copying of the buffer. No showpage :: your buffer's a trash-pointer, dude.

I do plan to sweep-up the auxiliary headers into a single `"xpost.h"` header file. But that's the full list you currently need from the top-level.

One obvious flaw is that there's currently no way to set the geometry or resolution. It's 1-pt per pixel, and that's that. It's also currently hardcoded at letter dimensions, (sorry, rest of the world). Does anybody have ideas about the best way to interface 
for that at the top level?

Any other options that a library user might want? Does the buffer-type `struct` need anything more than *height, width* and *stride*? Should `stride` count words or bytes?

In unixes, Cygwin and mingw, you can

```
hg clone https://luser.droog@code.google.com/p/xpost/
```

then read the INSTALL stuff, but the quick version is

```
./configure 
make 
sudo make install
```

then you can run

```
xpost_client
```

to produce a (buggy) rendering of a filled circle in xpost_client_out.ppm which loads ok for me in Gimp.

The program can also be browsed online at:

http://code.google.com/p/xpost/source/browse/src/bin/xpost_client.c
http://code.google.com/p/xpost/source/browse/src/lib/xpost.h
http://code.google.com/p/xpost/source/browse/src/lib/xpost_memory.h
http://code.google.com/p/xpost/source/browse/src/lib/xpost_object.h
http://code.google.com/p/xpost/source/browse/src/lib/xpost_context.h
http://code.google.com/p/xpost/source/browse/src/lib/xpost_interpreter.h

**Note:** I have also posted this code to [comp.lang.postscript](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.lang.postscript/5rikPCjtMBg) for a more **discussion**-type discussion.

**Also note:** The interpreter produces temporary files in the current directory named `gmemXXXXXX lmemXXXXXX xdumpXXXXXX` (where XXXXXX is a system-generated unique filename sequence) which may needlessly accumulate diskspace. They periodically must be manually removed. And be careful with code that may do an infinite series of pushes to the stack, `lmemXXXXXX` may grow very large to hold a huge stack.

Comment: I think that this is a well crafted question, with sufficient reviewable code included, but still short enough to be reasonably limited in scope. The full library code hosted on Google Code is useful supplementary information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on these two lines…

> ```
> xpost_create("bgr", 
>         XPOST_OUTPUT_BUFFEROUT, 
>         &buffer_type_object, 
>         XPOST_SHOWPAGE_RETURN, 
>         1); 
> xpost_run(XPOST_INPUT_STRING, prog);
> ```

I am puzzled by the interaction between `xpost_create()` and `xpost_run()`.  Is it possible to create and use multiple xpost contexts at once?  If so, shouldn't `xpost_create()` return some kind of handle that would be passed as a parameter to `xpost_run()`?  Or, if not, then why should I need to call `xpost_create()` and `xpost_destroy()` at all?

I would expect the library to behave more like a printer, in that it would produce an image for every `showpage` command.  One way to make that work would be to register a callback, which would be called whenever `showpage` is encountered.  Perhaps it could pass some information about the bounding box as parameters to the callback, since it's unreasonable to have to guess or hard-code that information.

It's odd that the color model is called `"bgr"`, but the pixel values are arranged in the opposite order (red, green, blue) in the output buffer.  I would also consider treating the buffer as an array of

```
typedef {
    int red;
    int green;
    int blue;
} struct pixel;
```

… instead of separate `red`, `green`, and `blue` integers.

Your example client doesn't seem to demonstrate any error-handling capability.  What happens, for example, if the PostScript interpreter has a stack underflow?

Comment: Yes, it can run multiple contexts with cooperative scheduling to support Display Postscript. Good point about the error handling. Oops. That's a bug in the pixel-ordering. Thanks. I get so confused with the dang buffers.

Comment: Also the same context can be re-used sequentially to factor-out the initialization in a batch job.

Comment: It currently uses a (shudder) *global variable* to hold the context-pointer created by `create` and used by `run`. So this definitely should be teased-out as a handle. Good catch.